# spring boot fails to run - IllegalAccessError on startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a strange issue and that I have not been able to resolve.  I am trying to use the sample JPA sprint boot (v0.5.0-M6) project as a starting point for an application I am writing.  I grabbed the JPA sample and got that to run locally.  I then proceeded to add my code into that project.  I imported into eclipse and run as spring-boot.   Then I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.core.io.DefaultResourceLoader$ClassPathContextResource from class org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getResourceByPath(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:386)
at org.springframework.core.io.DefaultResourceLoader.getResource(DefaultResourceLoader.java:100)
at org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.getResource(GenericApplicationContext.java:211)
at org.springframework.boot.context.initializer.ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.load(ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.java:192)
at org.springframework.boot.context.initializer.ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.load(ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.java:134)
at org.springframework.boot.context.initializer.ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.initialize(ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.java:121)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:403)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:287)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:749)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:738)
```

From what I can tell, this is the wrong application context, since I am not using XML configuration but annotations to drive the configuration.    Spring boot is automatically selecting this one and I need to tell it not to use the above.  At least that is what I think I need to do.

I did search here and in the spring.io forums but no one seems to have the same issue.

Question: What drives the selection of an application context with the auto configuration?

What should I be looking at to resolve the above issue?   What else do I need to provide to here help debug the auto configuration issue?

TIA,

Scott

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalAccessError` is usually a sign of environment problems. Maybe a bad jar file on the classpath, or the wrong JDK? Hard to say without some more detail. Did the sample work without your changes? What were the changes? Can you share the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same problem.
if you use maven check your pom.xml

remove conflict version in Spring Lib.

```
<properties>
       <hibernate.version>4.2.0.Final</hibernate.version>
       <mysql.connector.version>5.1.21</mysql.connector.version>
       <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
```

i remove this line

```
<spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

and in maven dependency just

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Your answer led me to the resolution of my issue.  It was because in my multi-module parent POM I had put in a dependency for a specific version (3.2.5) of spring-core.  I would not have imagined that to be the cause of the issue, but it appears it was.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: This helped me immensely as well! In my situation, I also had a multi-module parent POM. In my parent POM, I had to ensure the <spring.version> was set to the SAME VERSION as in the spring-boot-dependencies POM.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, and solved fixing the referencing to the boot-starter-parent pom.

At the pom.xml file I used:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.0.M6</version>
</parent>
```

I have some urgent issues to fix now, so I didn't inspected this parent pom to see what's so important here, but I hope this can help you - don't forget to verify the version you're using!